# How to set private static readonly datamembers of a static class?

Tags: c#

How to set private static readonly datamembers of a static class?

```
 public static class SessionInformation
 {
    private static readonly string UserName;
    private static readonly string PluginID;
    private static readonly string SessionID;
 }
```

I have some dynamic information which will be stored in this static class but I want that information not to be edited later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only set those in the static constructor, so either:

```
public static class SessionInformation
{
    private static readonly string UserName = "something";
    private static readonly string PluginID = "something else";
    private static readonly string SessionID = "some session";
}
```

or

```
public static class SessionInformation
{
  static SessionInformation()
  {
    UserName = "something";
    PluginID = "something else";
    SessionID = "some session";
  }
}
```

And no, it's not a good idea to store session information like this :) The problem is, that you have little control over when these values are actually assigned, because static members are actually quite complex. More importantly, you can't change them pretty much *ever*. Hence why classes like `HttpContext` don't use static fields, but rather, they are normal instances accessed through a static property like `HttpContext.Current`.

A more practical way would be to use some sort of singleton pattern, to give you more control over when the values are assigned, and allowing you to pass them as parameters. You'll then have the fields readonly, but assigned (once) from the outside.

Also, there could be a better solution if you aren't that focused on complete readonly, for example:

```
public static class SessionInformation
{
  private static bool hasBeenSet = false;

  public static string UserName { get; private set; }

  public static void SetValues(string userName)
  {
    if (hasBeenSet) return;

    UserName = userName;
    hasBeenSet = true;
  }
}
```

This does pretty much what you want without `readonly` fields - they are effectively readonly from the outside, though.

(note that this is a simple illustrative sample, it should be more robust, especially in a multithreaded environment)

Comment: Nope. I think OP looks for providing these values to class

Comment: @operation Which means you can't use `static readonly`, plain and simple.

Comment: @operation "dynamic" is a buzzword. You want to be able to change the value, but not change the value?

Answer (score 2):

The Singleton pattern mentioned in the other answer is what I believe you are looking for.

```
public class Session
{
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
    public string PluginId { get; private set; }
    public string SessionId { get; private set; }

    public static Session Current { get; private set; }

    public void NewSession(string userName, string pluginId, string sessionId)
    {
        Current = new Session 
        {
            UserName = userName,
            PluginId = pluginId,
            SessionId = sessionId
        };
    }

    private Session()
    {

    }   
}
```

Here you can create a new `Session` which you can access all over your application statically with `Session.Current` to get read access to your properties. The only way to change any of the values is from within the `Session` class or if you replace the current session using the `NewSession`-method.